# In ggplot2 scale_y_log10() transform appears to include negative values when there are none. What is going on?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a single column of sequence lengths to compare length distributions between several data sets.  There are no negative lengths and no lengths of zero.  I am using the following code:

```
ggk19 <- ggplot(all_frame, aes(x=length, fill=name, title="K-19")) + 
  geom_histogram(data=k19_frame, alpha=0.4, binwidth=0.02, fill='red',color='black') + scale_x_log10() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1000, color='blue', size=1, alpha=0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=5000, color='green', size=1, alpha=0.2)
```

Which produces this warning and this image:

```
Warning messages:
position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
```

[image]

But when I use scale_y_log10() I get funky looking graph with what appear to be negative values and an additional warning:

```
ggk19 <- ggplot(all_frames, aes(x=length, fill=name, title="K-19")) + 
  geom_histogram(data=k19_frame, alpha=0.4, binwidth=0.02, fill='red',color='black') + scale_x_log10() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1000, color='blue', size=1, alpha=0.2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=5000, color='green', size=1, alpha=0.2) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 14, base_family = "") + scale_y_log10()

Warning messages:
1: Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0 
2: position_stack requires constant width: output may be incorrect
```

[image]

Additionally, when I attempt to plot them over each other I get a staggered starting position when they should (and individually do) line up nicely at the same minimum length:

```
testplot <- ggplot(all_lengths_frame, aes(x=length, fill=name)) + 
    geom_histogram(data=subset(all_lengths_frame,name=="K-55"), alpha=0.3, binwidth=0.03) + scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10() +
    geom_histogram(data=subset(all_lengths_frame,name=="K-25"), alpha=0.3, binwidth=0.03) +
    geom_histogram(data=subset(all_lengths_frame,name=="K-29"), alpha=0.3, binwidth=0.03) +
    geom_histogram(data=subset(all_lengths_frame,name=="K-35"), alpha=0.3, binwidth=0.03)
```

[image]

I think all these problems might be related, but I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: You claim that none of your raw data is zero, but the issue would be that after binning you have a bin with a height of zero. So likely some of your bins are empty. Visually it seems plausible.

Comment: log of values < 1 will be negative.. what is `range(length)`

Comment: As pointed out by joran and @Legalizelt: Those are almost certainly bins with values <1.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, the x value is a raw count so the smallest number is 1- the very large values probably only have 1 per bin.  What about the staggering on the left side?